# How to set a background image in cocoa NSView

Tags: swift, image, cocoa, nsview

I have found several answers on the question how you can set a background image to a UIView in iOS.
However I was not able to solve this question for macOS and especially for cocoa. 
I have tried to set up something like

```
let bgImage = NSImage(named: "streaks")
let pattern = NSColor(patternImage: bgImage!)
self.view.layer?.background = pattern as! CGColor // this will fail on runtime
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike `UIView` `NSView` is not layer backed by default, you have to enable it.

```
self.view.wantsLayer = true
```

Then create the image and assign it to the `contents` property of the layer.

```
let image = NSImage(named: "streaks")
self.view.layer!.contents = image
```

Comment: Hi @vadian, yes , that does what I was looking for. 
Thank you 
Any chance you also know how to set this up as a tiled pattern image?

Comment: I'm not familiar with pattern image, but since you're dealing with a color write `self.view.layer!.backgroundColor = pattern.cgColor`

Comment: yes, that did the job. However it is not necessary to enable the layers. This works even without setting self.view.wantsLayer to true.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4

```
    self.view.wantsLayer = true
    let image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "streaks"))
    self.view.layer!.contents = image
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomImageView: NSView { 

    open override func makeBackingLayer() -> CALayer {
        let backingLayer = super.makeBackingLayer()
        let image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "imageName"))
        backingLayer.contents = image
        return backingLayer
    }
}
```